# How to do copy object using s3-transfer-manager?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, s3transfermanager

I am working on java project where I  am using s3 services so I am using aws-sdk version 2.17 and transfer manager 2.17 to perform operation like copy, upload, download.
My issue is that I want to show progress of copy process so I  am using copy api of transfer manager but it was not working .
Here are code snippet.

```
  public static void test(){
    try {
        String sAccessKey="XXXXX";
        String sSecretKey="XXXXXX";
        AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                sAccessKey,
                sSecretKey);
        AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider =  StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds);
        S3TransferManager s3TransferManager = S3TransferManager
                .builder()
                .s3ClientConfiguration(S3ClientConfiguration.builder()
                        .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider).build())
                .build();
      
        Copy copy = s3TransferManager.copy(c -> c
                        .copyObjectRequest(r -> r
                                .sourceBucket("source_bucket")
                                .sourceKey("test.json")
                                .destinationBucket("destination_bucket")
                                .destinationKey("test.json"))
                 .overrideConfiguration(o -> o.addListener( LoggingTransferListener.create()))
        );
        CompletedCopy completedCopy = copy.completionFuture().join();
        System.out.println(copy.progress().snapshot().transferSizeInBytes());
        System.out.println(copy.progress().snapshot().bytesTransferred());

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When I executes above mention code then I am getting error is:-

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: 6Y67D05YMB2VPCTZ, Extended Request ID: djU25dflTcZ0NExxqZQDXQ9SSwcQaMvvMAGrcfRDbDhvzgaws3twq1arytQ/Qd14kXNDpWYdbgA=)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the official document from AWS here?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-transfer-manager-to-copy-amazon-s3-objects/

Comment: this document is related to old version of s3transfermanger and I am using latest one.

Comment: Can you try to remove overrideConfiguration and put the System.out.println above CompletedCopy completedCopy = copy.completionFuture().join(); inside a while (!copy.completionFuture().isDone())

Comment: I think if you put system.out under CompletedCopy completedCopy = copy.completionFuture().join(); your code only executed after the copy process is done and it will throw the exception

Comment: its not working because I am getting copy.completionFuture().isDone() is false in every time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).